# Spring Boot warning: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have been digging around on the web and here the last two days to try to find a solution to this and I am coming up empty-handed. The application seems to function normally but I keep getting the warning mentioned in the title. It repeats itself regularly in the spring console and I have no idea what is causing it.

Full warning:

```
WARN 3652 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

As mentioned, this repeats itself the whole time I have the application running locally.

Here is the html page with the form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/" th:object="${url}" method="POST">
            <input th:field="*{longUrl}" type="url" placeholder="Url to shorten" />
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Shorten">
        </form>
        <div class="formstyle">
            <span class="longlink" th:text="${url.longUrl}"></span>
            <span class="shortlink" ><a th:href="@{${shortUrl}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" th:text="${shortUrl}"></a></span>
            <span class="copy"><button class="copybutton" onClick="copyUrl()">Copy</button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script th:inline="javascript">
function copyUrl() {
    var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
    tempInput.style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px";
    tempInput.value = /*[[${shortUrl}]]*/;
    document.body.appendChild(tempInput);
    tempInput.select();
    tempInput.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(tempInput);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Here is my controller class:

```java
package com.afairbairn.urlshrt.controller;

import com.afairbairn.urlshrt.entity.Url;
import com.afairbairn.urlshrt.service.UrlService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.net.URI;


@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private UrlService urlService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("url", new Url());
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String ConvertLongUrl(@ModelAttribute Url url, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String currUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        String shortUrl = urlService.ConvertLongUrlObject(url);
        shortUrl = currUrl + shortUrl;
        model.addAttribute("shortUrl", shortUrl);
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{shortUrl}")
    @Cacheable(value = "urls", key = "#shortUrl", sync = true)
    public ResponseEntity GetToRedirect(@PathVariable String shortUrl) {
        String url = urlService.ReturnLongUrl(shortUrl);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
                .location(URI.create(url))
                .build();
    }

}
```

This is my first post here so if I haven't provided some necessary details let me know.

TIA!

::UPDATE::

The problem has something to do with the second `@GetMapping`. When I remove it or comment it out the warning goes away. Just this line is causing the warning: `@GetMapping(value = "/{shortUrl}")`

Comment: Is the server publicly accessible? It's probably a vuln scan. What URL is being posted to?

Comment: @OrangeDog I am just running it locally (From IntelliJ). It is posting to "/".

Comment: Is it actually? You've checked e.g. the browser network tab? Put a breakpoint in that stacktrace?

Comment: Why do you post to base URL? Just change the post URL to sth. else

Comment: @OnurBaştürk The warning persists no matter what url I use.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes it is localhost: "Host: localhost:8080 Origin: http://localhost:8080 Referer: http://localhost:8080/"

Comment: @AndrewFairbairn none of those are the URL, only the host.

Comment: @OrangeDog Sorry, this is all new to me. If you meant the request URL it is also localhost: Request URL: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Well, when I look at your view, I feel that there should be only one object (URL) at your post method, but you have many objects at your controller method (Url, Method, BindingResult etc.). Please check out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation. And be sure to restart your application after you change your code

Comment: @OnurBaştürk Thank you for the suggestion. Even if I remove everything but the URL object the waning persists. Even if I comment out the whole post mapping I still see the warning. Is there something else that could be causing it?

Comment: Commenting the post mapping at the controller wouldn't change anything if you still try to post to base URL from your view. Just to make things simpler, first try to send just a string from your view to your post method.

Comment: @OnurBaştürk I will give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: Right, so I tired your suggestions and no luck. But, I did narrow it down. It has something to do with the last GET mapping. With this: "@GetMapping(value = "/{shortUrl}")" removed the waring goes away.